# Navigation Issue when navigating back in xamarin.forms for ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

In my app when I try to navigate back from a page that can navigate to another page the app no longer responds to anything and I receive this error from the output tab in visual studio:

## =================================================================
Native Crash Reporting

## Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.

This behavior only shows up on the ios version, android runs just fine. Am I missing an extra step for ios when it comes to navigation?

EDIT: The simulator used to debug the ios version was an iPhone 13 running iOS 15.4

EDIT 2: Here's the code used for navigation

MainVM:

```
 public async void ToFourth()
        {
            await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new FourthPage()));
            //await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new FourthPage());
        }
public Command TestCommand4 { get; set; }
public MainVM()
    {
        
        TestCommand4 = new Command(ToFourth);
    }
```

FourthVM

```
public FourthVM()
    {
        ToFifthCommand = new Command(ToFifth);
    }

    public Command ToFifthCommand{ get; set; }
    public async void ToFifth()
    {
        await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new FifthPage()));
        //await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new FifthPage());
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.MainPage"
          xmlns:buttons="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons;assembly=Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms">

<StackLayout>
  
    
   
    <buttons:SfButton Text="To fourth page" CornerRadius="5" Command="{Binding TestCommand4}"/>

</StackLayout>
```

FourthPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.FourthPage"
         xmlns:buttons="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons;assembly=Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <buttons:SfButton Text="To Fifth Page!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Command="{Binding ToFifthCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

FifthPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.FifthPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Fifth Page!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

FifthVM

```
 class FifthVM
{
}
```

When running the app on ios the user can go to FourthPage and from FourthPage they can go back and forth from FifthPage but if they return to MainPage the button to go to FourthPage no longer works and the output returns the native crash reporting error

EDIT 3: Here is the full error:

```
   =================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x1038320c5 - /Users/dssham/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E66EDCC-D588-48CC-BBC2-1F71091F0ACA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3A427101-65AB-4F75-BA68-934C6C4CED42/HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.iOS.app/HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x103826bbe - /Users/dssham/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E66EDCC-D588-48CC-BBC2-1F71091F0ACA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3A427101-65AB-4F75-BA68-934C6C4CED42/HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.iOS.app/HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x1038389f9 - /Users/dssham/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5E66EDCC-D588-48CC-BBC2-1F71091F0ACA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3A427101-65AB-4F75-BA68-934C6C4CED42/HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.iOS.app/HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x7fff6fafbdfd - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x600000759b60 - Unknown
    0x10a6c8e6a - Unknown

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7fff2018564a):0x7fff2018563a  00 00 00 00 00 90 4c 8b 57 08 48 8b 3f 49 89 f3  ......L.W.H.?I..
0x7fff2018564a  45 23 5a 18 49 c1 e3 04 
4d 03 5a 10 49 3b 33 75  E#Z.I...M.
Z.I;3u
0x7fff2018565a  0a 4d 8b 5b 08 4d 31 d3 41 ff e3 49 83 3b 01 76  .M.
[.M1.A..I.;.v
0x7fff2018566a  13 49 83 c3 10 49 3b 33 75 f1 4d 8b 5b 08 4d 31  .I...I;3u.M.[.M1

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Messaging:IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper <0x000e9>
      at UIKit.UIColor:get_CGColor <0x001da>
      at CoreFoundation.NativeObject:Dispose <0x00074>
      at Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Border.SfBorderRenderer:Dispose <0x0055a>
      at Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Buttons.SfButtonRenderer:Dispose <0x0007a>
      at Foundation.NSObject:Dispose <0x00074>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:Dispose <0x002c5>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:Dispose <0x00071>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:Dispose <0x0024a>
      at Foundation.NSObject:Dispose <0x00074>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.DisposeHelpers:DisposeModalAndChildRenderers <0x0030f>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:HandleCh
ildRemoved <0x000d2>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Element:OnDescendantRemoved <0x00120>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Element:OnChildRemoved <0x001c2>
      at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement:OnChildRemoved <0x0009a>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Page:InternalChildrenOnCollectionChanged <0x003c2>
      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1:OnCollectionChanged <0x000fa>
      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1:OnCollectionChanged <0x00103>
      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1:RemoveItem <0x0018a>
      at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1:Remove <0x001e5>
      at <Xamarin-Forms-INavigationPageController-RemoveAsyncInner>d__79:MoveNext <0x006d2>
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1:Start <0x00222>
      at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage:Xamarin.Forms.INavigationPageController.RemoveAsyncInner <0x001b2>
      at <UpdateFormsInnerNavigation>d__78:MoveNext <0x0035f>
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder:Start <0x001fa>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer:UpdateFormsInnerNavigation <0x0016a>
      at <DidMoveToParentViewController>d__45:MoveNext <0x001c2>
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder:Start <
0x0020a>
      at ParentingViewController:DidMoveToParentViewController <0x00182>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void__this___object <0x001ab>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x00254>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00172>
      at HelloWorldPublishTestForiOS.iOS.Application:Main <0x00092>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object <0x00198>
=================================================================
```

EDIT 4: After further testing it appears that the error occurs when using syncfusion elements like SfButton. Currently the AppDelegate.cs where all the Syncfusion Elements are initialized for ios looks like this:

```
 public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());
        Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Border.SfBorderRenderer.Init();
        Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Buttons.SfButtonRenderer.Init();
        Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Core.Core.Init();
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

In this project the only syncfusion nugets installed are Syncfusion.Xamarin.Buttons, Syncfusion.Xamarin.Buttons.iOS and Syncfusion.Xamarin.Core

EDIT 5: If the SfButton in the xaml is replaced with a regular Button navigation works as intended. The issue seems to occur when navigation is done using the SfButton

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I added the relevant code as well as the full error. will this help?

Comment: **1)** Return to MainPage with back button, or with some code? **2)** When going back and forth between 4th and 5th, are you ever "popping" pages? If so show that code. Or you just keep "pushing" on to nav stack (making the stack deeper and deeper)?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve there is no code for the 5th page, the user simply goes to the 4th page and presses a button to go to the 5th page and then uses the back button provided by xamarin to navigate back. the user then presses the back button again to return to main page and the app no longer responds

Comment: I'm assuming that the issue lies with the way ios handles navigation compared to android. The android version works perfectly fine

Comment: What you are seeing is not normal behavior. The code you show looks straightforward, and should work fine on any platform. I suggest making a new solution. Copy into it only the minimal source files necessary to show the problem. Make the pages as simple as possible - only the buttons you mention. Does it still happen in this new project? If so, please make a public github repo from it.

Comment: After creating a new project with no nugets navigation works fine. As detailed in the newest edit the issue appears to be caused by the syncfusion nugets

Comment: The public github repo for the test project is here: 
https://github.com/neoversi/XamarinNavigationTest
When sfbuttons are used, the Native Crash Error will appear in the output when going back from second page to first page